# Fetching facebook friends using koala gem is not returning all the friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, ruby-on-rails-4.1

The code I am using is directly from readme.

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
profile = @graph.get_object("me") // working perfectly fine..
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends") // returning only my friends which are there in developer/admin list of the app.
```

Anything I am missing?

PS: App is not approved yet.

Comment: Are you using API version 1.0 or 2.0? If 2.0 only friends who use the app and have granted user_friends permission to the app are shown

Comment: @lgy should i downgrade to 1? When its going away?

Comment: Which API version are you using? the answer depends on that - if you created the app ID after v2.0 was launched, you can't use v1.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions

Comment: I am not even getting list of selected friends who are using my application. Could you help me to get those friend list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook just release its API 2.0 which change many permissions and friend_* endpoint is one of them you can read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog). Your problem mentioned in the link as

> Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

Answer (score 0):

you simply add this line...

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(facebook_token)
# perfectly get facebook friends count :)
@friends = @graph.get_connection("me", "friends",api_version:"v2.0").raw_response["summary"]["total_count"]
```